# How can I display users in the chat list?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

In my project, when, for example, user1 asks for help, then user2 finds this request for help and writes to user1 to agree on further actions for help. My chat is registered in such a way that all users who can be written to are displayed on the left, namely, all registered users, and the chat itself is located to the right of this column. I would like the left column to display, for example, user2 (the one who helps) user1 (who is being helped) and those to whom he wrote earlier were displayed. Here is the chat code:
html code:

```
    {% extends 'chat/base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block header %}
<style>
    #user-list a.bg-dark {
        background-color: rgb(107, 107, 107) !important;
    }
    
    .list-group-item {
        cursor: pointer
    }
    
    .chat-bubble {
        min-width: 40%;
        max-width: 80%;
        padding: 5px 15px;
    }
    
    #user-list a:hover * {
        text-decoration: unset;
    }
    
    .chat-box {
        overflow: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
{% endblock %} {% block content %}
<div class="container" style="height: 75%;">
    <div class="card bg-dark h-100 border-light">
        <div class="card-body h-100">
            <div class="row h-100">
                <div class="col-md-4 border-right h-100">
                    <div class="list-group bg-dark" id='user-list'>
                        {% for u in users %} {% if not u.id == 1 and not u.id == user.id %}
                        <a class="list-group-item {% if u.id != chat_id %}bg-dark{% else %}bg-primary{% endif %} text-white" href="{% url 'chat-home' %}?u={{u.id}}">
                            <div>
                                <p>{{u.first_name}} {{u.last_name}} ({{u.username}})</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        {% endif %} {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 h-100">
                    {% if not chat_id > 0 %}
                    <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <h3>Start Chat now</h3>
                        <p><small class="text-muted">Please select a person to chat with.</small></p>
                    </div>
                    {% else%}
                    <div id="chat-box-field" class="h-100">
                        <div class="chat-box" style="height:80%">
                            {% for chat in chats %} {% if chat.user_from == user %}
                            <div class="p-2 w-100 d-flex justify-content-end">
                                <div class=" chat-bubble  ml-2 mb-2 bg-primary text-light rounded" data-id="{{chat.id}}">
                                    <p>{{chat.message}}</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><small>Ты</small> <small>{{chat.date_created|date:"M-d-Y H:i"}}</small></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="p-2 w-100 d-flex justify-content-start">
                                <div class="chat-bubble mr-2 mb-2 bg-light text-dark rounded" data-id="{{chat.id}}">
                                    <p>{{chat.message}}</p>
                                    <div class=" d-flex justify-content-between"><small>От</small> <small>{{chat.date_created|date:"M-d-Y H:i"}}</small></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %} {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-box-form border-top p-2" style="height:20%">
                            <div class="w-100 h-100">
                                <form action="" id="chat-submit" class="h-100 d-flex ">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="user_from" value="{{ user.id }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="user_to" value="{{ chat_id }}">
                                    <div class="col-md-10 h-100">
                                        <textarea name="message" id="" class="h-100 w-100 form-control" placeholder="Написать"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="button btn btn-primary h-100 w-100 justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex">Отправить</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %} {% block footer %}
<script>
    $(function() {
        if ($('.chat-bubble:last').length > 0) {
            $('.chat-box').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.chat-bubble:last').offset().top
            }, 'fast')
        }
        $('#chat-submit').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            start_loader()
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}'
                },
                url: "{% url 'chat-send' %}",
                method: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                error: err => {
                    console.log(err)
                    alert('an error occured')
                },
                success: function(resp) {
                    if (typeof resp == "object" && resp.status == 'success') {
                        location.reload()
                    } else {
                        consol.log(resp)
                        alert('an error occured')
                    }
                }
            })



        })
        chats_renew()
        setInterval(() => {
            chats_renew()
        }, 2500)

    })

    function chats_renew() {
        var last_id = 0
        if ($('.chat-bubble').length > 0)
            last_id = $('.chat-bubble:last').attr('data-id')
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}'
            },
            url: "{% url 'chat-renew' %}",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                last_id: last_id,
                user_id: '{{user.id}}',
                chat_id: '{{chat_id}}'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            error: err => {
                console.log(err)
                    // alert('an error occured')
            },
            success: function(resp) {
                if (Object.keys(resp).length > 0) {
                    Object.keys(resp).map(k => {
                        if (resp[k].id.user_from == '{{user.id}}') {
                            bubble = '<div class="p-2 w-100 d-flex justify-content-end">' +
                                '<div class=" chat-bubble  ml-2 mb-2 bg-primary text-light rounded" data-id="' + resp[k].id + '">' +
                                '<p>' + resp[k].message + '</p>' +
                                ' <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><small>You</small> <small>' + resp[k].date_created + '</small></div>' +
                                ' </div>' +
                                ' </div>';
                        } else {
                            bubble = '<div class="p-2 w-100 d-flex justify-content-start">' +
                                '<div class="chat-bubble mr-2 mb-2 bg-light text-dark rounded"  data-id="' + resp[k].id + '">' +
                                ' <p>' + resp[k].message + '</p>' +
                                ' <div class=" d-flex justify-content-between"><small>Sender</small> <small>' + resp[k].date_created + '</small></div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>';
                        }
                        // console.log(bubble)
                        $('.chat-box').append(bubble)
                        $('.chat-box').animate({
                            scrollTop: $('.chat-bubble:last').offset().top * 1000
                        }, 'fast')
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def get_messages(request):
    chats = chatMessages.objects.filter(Q(id__gt=request.POST['last_id']),Q(user_from=request.user.id, user_to=request.POST['chat_id']) | Q(user_from=request.POST['chat_id'], user_to=request.user.id))
    new_msgs = []
    for chat in list(chats):
        data = {}
        data['id'] = chat.id
        data['user_from'] = chat.user_from.id
        data['user_to'] = chat.user_to.id
        data['message'] = chat.message
        data['date_created'] = chat.date_created.strftime("%b-%d-%Y %H:%M")
        print(data)
        new_msgs.append(data)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(new_msgs), content_type="application/json")

def send_chat(request):
    resp = {}
    User = get_user_model()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post =request.POST
        
        u_from = UserModel.objects.get(id=post['user_from'])
        u_to = UserModel.objects.get(id=post['user_to'])
        insert = chatMessages(user_from=u_from,user_to=u_to,message=post['message'])
        try:
            insert.save()
            resp['status'] = 'success'
        except Exception as ex:
            resp['status'] = 'failed'
            resp['mesg'] = ex
    else:
        resp['status'] = 'failed'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Share your view function for this page

Comment: I have added views.py